# Mate 20 panel widget won't show temperature even though the box is checked

Tags: panel, calendar

On Mate 20 - Time and calendar panel widget won't show temperature even though the box is checked in preferences. Anybody know a workaround for this bug? Thanks.

Comment: It's YY.MM. Do you have 20.04 or 20.10?

Comment: Mate is a DESKTOP, and the version you're more likely to be using is 1.24 or something like that; we're decades away from Mate version 20.  Ubuntu releases (inc. *flavors* like Ubuntu-MATE) use the *year.month* format showing release, just as KGIII has stated; no *flavors* have a *year* release which is *snap* only for headless devices/appliances or cloud use (though a GNOME desktop can be added in *snap* form)  https://mate-desktop.org/

Answer (score 2):

If you're seeing something like "0°F", as in the first image below, then you'll need to specify your location to have the correct temperature.

[image: Zero Degrees]

1. Right click on the widget and choose "Preferences"
2. Ensure the units of measure are to your liking:
   [image: Units of Measure]
3. Set your location ... or something approximating it:
   [image: Set Location]
4. Confirm that you have data:
   [image: Have Data, Will Travel]

If this isn't what you mean when you are asking about widgets, do update your question with a screenshot of what you're seeing, as a picture is worth a thousand words